# Unclear Azure ID starting with 'S-'

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

we've got an application which uses the GraphAPI in order to save Name, Mail etc. from the logged in users. Also some other AD-Apps has access to our application.
Now we got in our Database the following ID: 
S-1-3XX-0-0-3077XXXXXX-1078XXXXXX-425XXXXXX-3868XXXXXX

I think this is the ApplicationIdentifier? But how can I find now the belonging application to this id?

Comment: Looks like an on-prem AD security identifier. Could be an attribute on a user.

Comment: What is the column name of the value in your database?

Comment: The column name is: HttpContext.User.Identity.Name and the identifier is every time the same, also with other users

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the value of onPremisesSecurityIdentifier.

[image]